# Random Generator with range + exception

Tags: java, random, generator

I want to create a random generator with a range (defined by `var1`), and an exception (defined by `blockvar1`)

I wrote this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int var1 = rand.nextInt(var1) + 1;
do{
    blockvar1 = rand.nextInt(var1) + 1;
}
while (var1 == blockvar1);
```

Comment: No reason for the while, just do `if(var1 >= blockvar1) { var1++; }` Apart from that, what does *"it didn't work"* exactly mean?

Comment: what't your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. It creates an integer given a max value and a min value and does not generate the number given in the third parameter.

```
public static Integer RandomNumberRange(int max, int min, int block)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum;

    do {
        randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    } while (randomNum == block && (max != block && block != min));

    return randomNum;
}
```

Example Output of calling the function with a range of 5-1 and 2 as blocking

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        System.out.print(RandomNumberRange(5, 1, 2) + " ");

}//main method
```

Output

```
1 5 5 1 5 4 3 3 4 1 5 5 5 1 5 4 3 5 1 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I’ve got two (minor) issues with your code:

1. You seem to be using `var1` for two purposes, it’s both the upper bound for your random number and the random number itself; this causes confusion and a result that may not be as expected (even if expectation is blurred when it comes to random numbers).
2. I’m not very fond of the loop. In practice it won’t run forever, still there is no hard upper bound on how many times it will run.

Here’s my suggestion instead:

```
private static Random rand = new Random();

/**
 * Generates a pseudo-random number in the range 0..var1, but not blockvar1
 * @param var1 upper bound (inclusive) of random number
 * @param blockvar1 forbidden number
 * @return the generated random number
 */
public static int randomNumberRange(int var1, int blockvar1) {
    if (blockvar1 < 0 || blockvar1 > var1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("blockvar1 must be between 0 and var1 inclusive");
    }
    int result = rand.nextInt(var1);
    if (result >= blockvar1) {
        result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Sample output from repeated calls to `randomNumberRange(4, 2)`:

```
1 1 3 3 1 0 0 0 4 4 1 0 3 3 4 3 3 0 1 3
```

You will notice it gives you numbers from 0 to 4 inclusive except never 2.